# How can I optimize this NumPy code?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numeric

I have the following code that is the bottleneck in my Python code:

```
def get_payoff(self,  actual, predicted):
    if abs(actual - 1.0) < 1e-5:  # if actual == 1
        if predicted < 0.5:
            return self.fn_payoff * (0.5 - predicted)
        elif predicted > 0.5:
            return self.tp_payoff * (predicted - 0.5)
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        if predicted < 0.5:
            return self.tn_payoff * (0.5 - predicted)
        elif predicted > 0.5:
            return self.fp_payoff * (predicted - 0.5)
        else:
            return 0

def get_total_payoff(self):
    total_payoff = 0
    for target_element, prediction_element in zip(np.nditer(self.target), np.nditer(predictions)):
        total_payoff += self.get_payoff(target_element, prediction_element)
```

fn_payoff, tp_payoff, tn_payoff, and fp_payoff are all floats. 
self.target and self.predictions are both numpy ndarrays.

I assume there's some way to do replace the for loop in get_total_payoff with some kind of numpy vectorization, but I don't know how to handle the if/then statements to do the vectorization properly.

Comment: `def float get_payoff()` -- Er, is that a typo or are you using an obscure statically-typed variant of Python?

Comment: Oops, I was converting the Cythonized version to python for the question and I forgot to remove that. I'll fix it

Comment: Is `predictions` supposed to be a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def _get_payoff(self, actual, predicted):
    pred_factor = numpy.abs(0.5 - predicted)
    payoff_selector = 2*numpy.isclose(actual, 1) + (predicted < 0.5)
    payoff = numpy.choose(payoff_selector,
                          [
                              self.fp_payoff,
                              self.tn_payoff,
                              self.tp_payoff,
                              self.fn_payoff,
                          ])
    return numpy.sum(payoff * pred_factor)

def get_total_payoff(self):
    return self._get_payoff(self.target, predictions)
```

We use [`numpy.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html#numpy.choose) to generate an array of payoff selections and multiply that with an array of absolute differences between `0.5` and the prediction values, then sum. `numpy.isclose` is used to test whether the `actual` values are close to 1. We can ignore the `predicted == 0.5` case, since multiplying by `numpy.abs(0.5 - predicted)` gives the correct result of 0 anyway. If `self.target` and `predictions` are guaranteed to be 1D, `numpy.dot` is likely to perform better than separately multiplying and summing.

Comment: You can only ignore the `predicted==0.5` case if what you multiply by is not NaN. Otherwise, you get NaN, not 0.

Comment: @shx2: We're multiplying by one of the 4 payoff factors, though. I doubt those are NaN. If they are, it's not clear whether the output should also have NaNs.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that in that case your function differs from the original. Not clear that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

The key for vectorizing functions which use different expressions based on a condition is using [`np.choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html).  Also, in your case, `predict-0.5` and `0.5-predict` can be replaced by `abs(predict-0.5)`, plus special handling of the case where `predict==0.5` (I'm guessing the special handling is there for correct handling of NaN's).

```
import numpy as np

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fn_payoff = 222.
        self.tn_payoff = 444.
        self.fp_payoff = 777.
        self.tp_payoff = 888.
        self.target = np.array([ 0.3, 1., 2. ])
        self.predictions = np.array([ 0.4, 0.5, 1.7 ])

    def get_payoff(self,  actual, predicted):
        if abs(actual - 1.0) < 1e-5:  # if actual == 1
            if predicted < 0.5:
                return self.fn_payoff * (0.5 - predicted)
            elif predicted > 0.5:
                return self.tp_payoff * (predicted - 0.5)
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            if predicted < 0.5:
                return self.tn_payoff * (0.5 - predicted)
            elif predicted > 0.5:
                return self.fp_payoff * (predicted - 0.5)
            else:
                return 0

    def get_total_payoff(self):
        total_payoff = 0
        for target_element, prediction_element in zip(np.nditer(self.target), np.nditer(self.predictions)):
            total_payoff += self.get_payoff(target_element, prediction_element)
        return total_payoff

    def get_total_payoff_VECTORIZED(self):
        actual_mask = np.abs(self.target - 1) < 1e-5
        predict_mask = self.predictions < 0.5
        payoff_n = np.choose(actual_mask, [ self.tn_payoff, self.fn_payoff ])
        payoff_p = np.choose(actual_mask, [ self.fp_payoff, self.tp_payoff ])
        payoff = np.choose(predict_mask, [ payoff_p, payoff_n ]) * abs(self.predictions-0.5)
        payoff[self.predictions==0.5] = 0
        return payoff.sum()

a = A()
print a.get_total_payoff()
=> 976.8
print a.get_total_payoff_VECTORIZED()
=> 976.8
```